# Grammar issues in haskell with data definitions

Tags: haskell, grammar, parsec

I'm attempting to implement a grammar in haskell using the parsec library but I'm having issues with expected Vs. actual types as defined in the grammar, I know the answer to my question is no doubt simple/obvious but alas there is something I'm not understanding...

An excerpt of data declaration follows (should be sufficient to diagnose):

```
data Expr1 = SeqOfExpr1 [Expr1]
            | Lambda Expr8 Expr1
            | List Expr2 Expr1
            | If Expr2 Expr1 Expr1
            | Expr2
              deriving (Show)

data Expr2 =  SeqOfExpr3 [Expr3]
              deriving (Show)

data Expr3 =  SeqOfExpr4 [Expr4]
              deriving (Show)
 ----------------------------Redundant Code Omitted------------------------------
expr1 :: Parser Expr1   
expr1 = declaration
      <|> list
      <|> ifStmt
      <|> expr2

declaration :: Parser Expr1
declaration =
    do  reservedOp "\\"
        var <- name
        reservedOp "->"
        expr <- expr1
        return $ Lambda var expr

list :: Parser Expr1    
list =
    do exprA <- expr2
       reservedOp ":"
       exprB <- expr1
       return $ List exprA exprB
```

Now there are further data declarations for expressions down to Expr8 but they are much the same as expr2 -> expr3 the different between them is how they are delimited e.g. Expr3's are delimited by "||", Expr4's by "&&" etc.

One of issues I'm having (which if solved should provide me with the idea to fix the rest):

The List value constructor returns an Expr1 which causes a conflict:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Expr2' with actual type `Expr1'
In the first argument of `List', namely `exprA'
In the second argument of `($)', namely `List exprA exprB'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: return $ List exprA exprB
```

I think it's because I'm using Expr2 as a value declaration in Expr1 but I'm not sure how to correct the grammar to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Sean

Comment: Why do you need all these `Expr<n>` data types?  Why not parse them as simply `Expr`, and then apply type checking?

Comment: It doesn't even look like an issue of type checking. If you're introducing several expression *parsers* due to operator priorities, you still do not necessarily need to introduce several expression datatypes as well, as in the abstract syntax, operator priorities are typically fully explicit anyway. So you can have `expr<n>` parser functions that all return an `Expr` result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `data Expr1`, you have a nullary constructor `Expr2`. I suspect you meant that to be something like

```
data Expr1 =
           ...
           | Foo Expr2
```

to wrap an `Expr2`.

Anyway, as per

```
expr1 :: Parser Expr1   
expr1 = declaration
      <|> list
      <|> ifStmt
      <|> expr2
```

the compiler infers `expr2 :: Parser Expr1`, but when you try

```
list :: Parser Expr1    
list =
    do exprA <- expr2
       reservedOp ":"
       exprB <- expr1
       return $ List exprA exprB
```

the type of `List` means `exprA` must be an `Expr2`, but from `expr2`'s type, the compiler knows `exprA :: Expr1`.

So you probably need to wrap `expr2` in `list`,

```
list = ...
     <|> fmap Foo expr2
```

if you change the definition of `Expr1` to include a `Foo` constructor to wrap an `Expr2`.